# audio playback in c4 framework (c4iOS

Tags: c4

new user to c4iOS framework. Working my way thru the tutorials/examples - wondering how one goes about playing back audio (as opposed to video, which is covered in the example texts).

thanks in advance for answering my less-than-advance 'n00b' question

-jf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio samples are fairly similar to movie objects, albeit they don't have an option like `shouldAutoplay` that will get them running as soon as the application loads.

The easiest way to construct a sample is like this:

```
@implementation C4WorkSpace {
    C4Sample *audioSample;
}

-(void)setup {
    audioSample = [C4Sample sampleNamed:@"C4Loop.aif"];
}
```

Which builds the audio sample object as a variable that you can then reference in other methods. For instance, if you want to play a sound clip when you first touch the screen you would do the following:

```
-(void)touchesBegan {
    [audioSample play];
}
```

To toggle the playback for each touch, you would do something like:

```
-(void)touchesBegan {
    if(audioSample.isPlaying) {
        [audioSample stop];
    } else {
        [audioSample play];
    }
}
```

A working copy of a C4 app that toggles playback can be found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/3774225).

There are also a lot of properties for audio samples that let you control things like playback rate, volume, panning and so on.

An example of changing the volume is like this:

```
audioSample.volume = 0.5; //0 = mute, 1 = full volume
```

An example of skipping to a specific time in a sample would be like:

```
audioSample.currentTime = 1.0f; //this will put the "playhead" to 1.0 second
```

You can have a look at the [C4Sample documentation](http://www.c4ios.com/docs/Classes/C4Sample.html) to see more properties and other aspects of the class. The documentation is also available via the Xcode organizer.